# Can i add value in Setting.bundle via .m file?

Tags: ios, dynamic, settings.bundle, info.plist

I am working on SMS app. I want to add the registered number in the Setting.Bundle dynamically.

1. How can I set .plist value dynamically in Setting.bundle when a user clicks on the Register button?
2. How do I add a number in Settings.bundle?

I don't understand how to get a value on a click event and then show that in Setting.bundle dynamically. For example, while a user registers in app I want to show his/her number in setting of my application.

Comment: Need code for that .. Urgent .. You ready to pay man? And really, I'm not even going to edit this. My eyes bleed.

Comment: @Kheldar i need help so i wrote urgent .. And wht problem u facing in this question ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not use `NSUserDefaults`?

```
NSNumber *yourvalue = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:1];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:yourvalue forKey:@"yourkey"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Then get it from defaults like that:

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSNumber *value = [defaults objectForKey:@"yourkey"];
```

Comment: Full details: http://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Preferences/Preferences.html

Comment: Thanks . but actually i want to write it through code ..My main purpose is that i want to display my register number in setting while i register in app .. Like i want to fatch number from app and want to write that in setting bundle .. need code for that ...